# http request interceptor - restful web service using cxf

Tags: java, rest, cxf

Trying to add headers to every request that my restful service receives. The below inbound http interceptor gets invoked, but does not add the header.

```
    package com.client.interceptors;

    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
    import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
    import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
    import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;

    public class ClientInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
        public ClientInterceptor() {
            super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE); // Put this interceptor in this phase
            System.out.println("inside constructor");
        }

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) throws Fault {
            // process the message

            System.out.println("inside interceptor");
            Map<String, List> headers = (Map<String, List>) msg
            .get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);

            headers.put("token",
            Collections.singletonList("abcd1234xyz56sa"));

            msg.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);

        }
    }
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: but are u calling restful webservice?

Comment: yes, it's a simple GET service and i invoke from the browser

Comment: if u just want to inwoke from the browser then u can use Tool for the same na Poster :)

Comment: yes, but i want to be able to add it programmatically so that I dont have to change every time I access the service.

Answer (score 0):

Well ya i have one solution for the same. look this. it might help.

```
Client client = Client.create();
     WebResource webResource =client.resource("URL");

     MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
     queryParams.add("json", js); //set parametes for request

     appKey = "Addkey " + appKey; // appKey is unique number

     //Get response from RESTful Server get(ClientResponse.class);
     ClientResponse response = null;
     response = webResource.queryParams(queryParams)
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                            .header("Authorization", appKey)
                            .get(ClientResponse.class);

     String jsonStr = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks but this again ties it down to the client. What I want to do is add it at the service end. It should be added irrespective of what my client is, be it from a java rest client or an ajax call from a browser.

Comment: means u need to add it from client side i mean when u call address isn't it?

Comment: adding at client site should not be an issue. I want to be able to add at server side irrespective of the client/request. To give background, I am basically building a mock rest service that looks for these headers, hence preferring to add at service end, instead of client side.

Comment: if u really doing that from client side i mean u can give response into the json but u need to have that annotation for the same.